# CSS Background-Image don't displays (Laravel 7.x)

Tags: html, css, laravel, background

Good morning, I'm working in a project and I need to put a background image inside a div below the navbar, so I putted the Background-Image property and the url.
But when I load the localhost page I don't see the image displayed as I wish. I tried to put the url directly inside the div as style property and putting it as a URL::asset, but also didn't work. If someone can help me it would be great!

Here you have the div i created in the blade file:

```html
    <div id="backgroundImage">
        <h1>THE PLANET FOR WOMEN ENTREPRENEURS</h1>
    </div>
```

And here you have the CSS:

```css
#backgroundImage{
    background-image: url('/public/storage/images/backgrounds/Coworking.JPG');
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

The images are saved in that route, is the absolute path, not the relative.

But when I load the page this is the display:
[image: Page loaded]

Comment: Does the url path accessible? Check the `network` tab in your browser console to see if there's a 404 error

Comment: Yes, It returns me a 404

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base path is `public` so you don't have to put it in the path. Just remove `/public` from the path:

```
#backgroundImage{
    background-image: url('/storage/images/backgrounds/Coworking.JPG');
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#backgroundImage{
    background-image: url({{asset('/storage/images/backgrounds/Coworking.JPG')}});
    width: 100vh;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

I think this works fine.

Comment: It didn't work, that only maded that width and height displayed all the page as I wanted, but the image don't displays

Answer (score 1):

You have to put your images folder (as the backgrounds folder name you are using) in the **`public`** folder.

Now in the CSS file:

```
background: url('/images/backgrounds/Coworking.JPG');
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just **deleted storage folder in pulblic** folder and reset the symbolic link using **php artisan storage:link**